# Traduire « cover all loose ends »

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

Comment est-ce qu'on pourrait traduire l'expression anglaise « Cover all loose ends » ?

J'ai pensé à « couvrir toutes les issues », mais je suis pas sûr.

Signification: *cover all loose ends* in the sense of making sure nothing is forgotten.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Une traduction approximative serait « ne rien laisser au hasard ». Mais selon le contexte le sens de cette expression peut varier considérablement.

---

A loose translation would be “*ne rien laisser au hasard*”. But depending on the context, the meaning of this expression might be very different.

Comment: C'est la reponse la plus correcte

Answer (score 1):

IL ne s'agit pas, de ce que je peux en dire d'après une recherche rapide, d'une seule expression, mais du verbe *cover* suivi de l'expression *loose ends*. Je trouve des exemples liés au sens de "camoufler" (*cover up*), et d'autres au sens de "prévoir".

En l'absence de contexte, je peux te dire que ta traduction ne peut pas être correcte, mais il n'est pas possible de dire quelle serait une traduction acceptable en l'occurrence car les différents sens possibles n'ont à peu près aucun liens entre eux.